# SpringBoot unit test controller mvc return always 404

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to run a simple unit test for my controllers but for all requests I try `MockMvc` returns me a 404 error.

Here is a sample of controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/airports")
public class AirportController {

    private final AirportRepository repository;

    ...

    @GetMapping(value = "/no-page", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public List<Airport> noPage() {
        try {
            return repository.findAllByActive(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to retrieve from DB!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And a test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AirportControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testAirportController() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/airports/no-page"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

(The request is on /api because it's my servlet context)

The status is never 200 (what it should be), but always 404 not found.
I also try to create a test configuration like this and import it to my test:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.project")
public class TestConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

But it changes nothing.

What is wrong with my test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AirportController` is mapped to `/airports`. Therefore your test should also use that path as follows:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/airports/no-page"))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Please note that `MvcMock` test runs independent of the configured servlet context path.

Comment: I edited my request, I have api as servlet context so my url is /api/airports/no-page

Comment: I've also update my answer: `MockMvc` does not use the configured servlet context path. As you are running tests against your MVC controllers in isolation, the servlet context path should not matter.

Comment: If you find it important to specify the context path (which again, should usually not be the case), you can provide it as follows: `var builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/airports").contextPath("/api");`. Then you can pass in the builder to `MockMVC` as follows: `this.mockMvc.perform(builder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());`